# Node.js socket.io with ssl connection

Tags: node.js, ssl, socket.io

I am trying to connect node.js server with socket.io using ssl. My server has windows 2008 server and iis installed. I intalled ssl my domain name on IIS and I can connect with my domain via http s://mydomain.com. But I cant connect my node.js server with ssl. I am using following code on my server,Have you got any ideas what the problem might be?

```
  var fs =    require('fs');

  var options = {
  pfx: fs.readFileSync('sslkey.pfx'),
  passphrase:'password'
    };

    var express = require('express'),
        app = express(),
        server = require('https').createServer(options,app),    
        server2 = require('http').createServer(app),    
        io = require('socket.io').listen(server, {log: true});

    function sendCrossDomain(req, res){
    //return;
        res.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
        res.sendfile(__dirname + '/crossdomain-test.xml');
    };

    app.get('/crossdomain.xml', sendCrossDomain);
    app.get('/', sendCrossDomain);

    server.listen(9595);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no errors about your certificate when you run the node program,

I would check to make sure the firewall port is opened on TCP 9595.

You will also have to request the page with https://yourdomain.com:9595 in order to access the running program since it's SSL and on a different port than 443.